# How to read properties from eclipse.ini file programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to find how to get properties from the file eclipse.ini (or launcher.ini - for our product). I have trying to find it during already two days, but all to no avail.

One of several methods, which I have tried:

```
String[] args = Platform.getApplicationArgs();
```

and also

```
String[] commandLineArgs = Platform.getCommandLineArgs();
```

Comment: Properties defined by `-Dxxx` are just ordinary Java properties - `System.getProperty`. Other things have more specialised APIs, so you need to be clear exactly what you want to get.